# Use php as a browser

Tags: php, javascript

I am looking for a way to let php act as a browser, does anyone know how to do that? I now how to get pages and how to send get/post forms, but How do i let php interact with AJAX and javascript on a web page?

Comment: You would need to create your own browser on PHP, you would need to read and interpret the JS code on your page and act accordingly.. maybe there is already some project that takes care of that, but it doens't sound like it's that easy to do.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. Browsers are client-side applications, PHP is not...

Answer (score 5):

Don't. PHP is not designed for this sort of thing. While conceivably possible, this'll take an extraordinary amount of work.

Use something designed for this sort of use case, like [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/).

And please, don't be evil. Using this to get around valid anti-bot restrictions would be lame.

Comment: Thanks! I think i only need to enter some user+pass and then send with a javascript form. It's only that action. Surely that it's not possible to do this easily if its only one login form?